# ASP.NET MVC: When to use HTML helpers in views - Tidying up the code!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am trying to refactor my views a bit and up til now i have been using the built HTML helpers but i thought i would create my own - they're extension methods right?

I wonder if anyone can confirm or give advise when an HTML is needed? I think i once saw a document that said if you use 1 IF statement in your views encapsulate it into a html helper - would anyone agree with that?

With regards to creating html helpers, would it be better to create my own class rather than add extension methods to the HTML class that ships with MVC? Any body have ideas on this?

Or possible i shouldn't bother with HTML helpers and just use the built in ones and continue to use my IF statements within views.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we assume you are using the standard view engine?

Comment: very good question - yes currently i am using the standard webform view engine. When Razor is more stable and documentation is available then i will probably switch. I presume razor still supports HTML helpers and still a good idea to use with razor - or does razor change the rules :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML helpers when you want to encapsulate the output of a piece of HTML markup that can take varying values.

I'd recommend creating them as extension methods to `HtmlHelper` rather than creating your own class, as your own class won't be available inside of the default `ViewPage` without either instantiating a new instance inside of the View or subclassing `ViewPage` and using this in the View (or passing in on the model, but that's just *wrong*!).

Comment: Thanks russ, so basically when i am over using the IF statement - its times to put it in the HTML helper?

Comment: Well, it depends. I like the idea of dumb views, thin controllers and fat models and therefore try and keep anything but really simple logic out of views. It might make sense to move the logic into a helper, if you need to render similar markup with different values in different cases. Or it might make sense to use different partial views, or a different view altogether if the logic is more complex. What are you doing in the if statement?

Comment: Actually i am using a partial view to setup my login toolbar... it either displays Login or Welcome [Name of User]. There are a few ifs in the partial view. Another thing i am doing is displaying a message box / information toolbar that displays important messages. This has a number of ifs and actually is in my master page. I am probably using ifs in a number of other places where what is displayed depends on User.Identtity and a number of other things - does this help?

Comment: What you describe sounds, in my personal opinion, sounds like reasonable logic to have in the view. If you find that you're doing lots of if conditions to check for the same condition throughout a view, I'd be inclined to separate out into two partial views and have the one if statement in the view in which the partial will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Helpers are extension methods. I can confirm as well that I too use the 'if' rule when it comes to views. **Any** view logic coded should, IMO, be in a helper.

You can use helper to render custom markup, or control which markup(ie existing view) is displayed.

Not too sure about the ease of this, but it does lend itself to more unit testing (please comment on this aspect if someone has more info).

> With regards to creating html helpers, would it be better to create my own class rather than add extension methods to the HTML class that ships with MVC? Any body have ideas on this?

If I understand correctly, in this respect my suggestion would to separate your helpers into their own classes. The reasoning behind this for me would be that you easily know when looking at your views what are standard helpers vs the ones you've created. I think this will improve maintainability.

> i shouldn't bother with HTML helpers and just use the built in ones and continue to use my IF statements within views.

I'd say **No!** *(or it depends)*. One of the benefits of using a helper would be to reuse the same view logic in multiple views as opposed to re-coding the same `if` statements. This means your code is more DRY, which is always better. In the event you need to debug some weirdness error, you only need to look in one place, the newly created helper.